# Single word request for ..love-ditsy

Tags: single-word-requests

**Movie scene:** girl has back turned to 'dreamy' leading boy and is talking softly about, moonlight, white picket fences, and footsie sounds of little scampering children in onesies - and maybe holding a flower with a smile plastered across her face.

Probably cast Sandra Dee.  (The more melodramatic and kitsch the better.)

*“There is this old movie where the girl is all ________.”*

Comment: Saccharine? Bucolic (in the insipid, mawkish sense, not the pastoral sense)?

Comment: "Love-struck" is the first word that comes to mind.  (And of course there's "love sick" later in the relationship, when the girl/boy briefly loses the boy/girl before finding him/her again.)

Comment: @Hot Licks - To my mind _"love-struck”_ is the clearest and most precise answer yet given, so thank you, but as yours is only a wee comment I have the opportunity to reward _“twitterpated”_ below as the accepted Answer. : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holding a flower with a smile plastered on her face?

[image: Definitely twitterpated]

Sounds like she might be [twitterpated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/twitterpated)

> North American informal
>   1. Infatuated or obsessed:
>
> - Gus is still hopelessly twitterpated by Lee
> - smiling into each other’s eyes, a seemingly twitterpated couple glided
>
> 1.1 In a state of nervous excitement:
>
> Origin
>   1940s: from twitter + -pated 'having a head or mind of a specified kind' (from pate); popularized by the 1942 film [Bambi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034492/).

<sup>OxfordDictionaries.com</sup>
<sup>Image used without permission</sup>

Comment: Wow, that's a cool word. And a new one for me! Now I have to go look up its etymology.

Comment: Great word, even though it's a  near-miss to the OP's requirement, imo. Now I can't wait to tell someone that they are twitterpated. (It would have worked better before the era of the microblogging site)

Comment: @Patrick - Nice work!  [checking to see who nabbed the 'twitterpated' user name on Twitter]  My only concern was having to re-read the OED first example 4 times because of the boy-boy naming, as it didn't register what was meant.  Is that purposefully obtuse/political at the expense of clarity?  When did the OED start that?  OR... is that purposefully _exact_, and the general usage may be understood to be _'homosexual informal'_?  (I have no idea what I'm talking about; in this wild and woolly world.)  Great find!

Comment: @ipso an, Lee is a gender neutral name. Some quick googling revealed many people think Leigh is the appropriate feminine spelling - they may be right, but either way, the confusion is understandable. That said, boys are more than capable of being twitterpated over other boys and girls over other girls (and a girl over a boy) - twitterpated is a non-gendered verb, like most of the words in English.

Answer (score 8):

**[starry-eyed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/starry-eyed)**?

> full of emotion, hopes or dreams about somebody/something in a way that is not realistic
>
> *I remember when you were all starry-eyed about Rob.*

Comment: Currently lots of votes, but in my hypothetical movie scene the girl gets the boy, or possibly gets the boy.  Had she done the same about Brad Pitt or whatever, some unobtainable celebrity, then _“starry-eyed”_ would be perfect.  [script rewrite needed!]

Comment: @ipso: Well, to be fair, you didn't specify that. Also seeing as you accepted love-struck earlier, I must say that I thought of that, but the `all` before the blank threw me off. `She's all love-struck` doesn't sound like something someone would prefer over `she's love-struck`. I might add that even though `twitterpated` is awesome, it doesn't really mean what you asked for. It's just another word for infatuation/excitement

Answer (score 4):

**"dewy"?**

Can you make Hallmark Cards an adjective?

Comment: @Pugh - I'm liking _dewy_!  I'll keep the question open though as I think there is another term for this love condition.  (_“Got it bad”_ is an idiom one hears in old movies as well.)

Answer (score 3):

> [**soppy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soppy)
>   sad or romantic in a foolish or exaggerated way
>
> **cloying**
>   too good or kind, or expressing feelings of love in a way that is not sincere:
>
> **[lovey–dovey](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lovey-dovey)**
>   There is this old movie where the girl is all **lovey-dovey**.

Comment: _'Soppy'_ seems the perfect word, but as an American I've never really heard that British informal usage (although 'soapy' gets a look too.)  And _'Lovey-dovey'_ worked best before a couple of others just came up.

Comment: I've never heard 'soppy', but I've heard 'sappy', which means the same thing as far as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

"Love-struck" is the first word that comes to mind. (And of course there's "love sick" later in the relationship, when the girl/boy briefly loses the boy/girl before finding him/her again.)